# Can't get response from wcf client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I made client application for consuming java web service. When i post request by SOAPUI i got regular response, but running same request from wcf client give me an error:

**"The header 'Security' from the namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that ...**

My request look like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-    open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">&#xD;
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-Comtrade" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">&#xD;
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>&#xD;
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>&#xD;
        </wsse:UsernameToken>&#xD;
    </wsse:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <getPortedOutMsisdnsByDate xmlns="http://www.ericsson.com/schema/ts_sdp/portedinout/v1_0/local">
        <msisdnsDate>2014-03-14T10:32:43.1896067+01:00</msisdnsDate>
    </getPortedOutMsisdnsByDate>
</s:Body>
```

My client config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://x.x.x.x:8080/SubscriptionManagerService/services/SdpPortedInOut"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SdpBinding"
      contract="ISdpPortedInOut" name="Sdp" >
    <headers>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstand='1' xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-Comtrade' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
          <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
    </headers>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Changing mustUnderstand to 0 doesn't solve problem.